# Running powershell from process acts different then from PowerShell ISE

Tags: c#, powershell, process, outlook

I've got PowerShell script that acts like expected if I run it from PowerShell ISE.

```
$ol = @()
$ProcessActive = Get-Process outlook -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($ProcessActive -eq $null)
{
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
}
else
{
$ol = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application")
}
$file = "c:\testfile.pdf"

$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.Recipients.Add("test@test.nl") 
$mail.Subject = "This is a subject"
$mail.HTMLBody = "<html><body><h3>Hello world</h3></body></html>"
$mail.Attachments.Add($file)
$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```

However ... if I start a process in C# to execute the script it will only work if the Outlook process is not running.

```
        var filename = "script.ps1";
        var fullname = path + filename;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullname))
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"& '{0}'", fullname);
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            System.IO.File.Delete(fullname);
        }
```

The process eventually ends execution and the file is deleted in both cases (outlook running or not).

What do I need to change in order to let the script execute properly when started from a C# process (even if Outlook is running)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger in C# I use the file that contains the powershell script and pass it like an argument on this line:startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"& '{0}'", fullname);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to answer what the difference was between script and process I've created a log of the process that was running the script. To create the log i've used

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\log.txt",process.StandardError.ReadToEnd())
```

First the exception was: missing references. After fixing the missing reference by adding at the top of the powershell script :

```
Add-Type -Path 'Dir\To\Dll'
```

After that I received another error:

```
Exception calling "GetActiveObject" with "1" argument(s): "Operation unavailabl
e (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))"
```

I've read some articles and this has to do with that Outlook does not allow different users 'using' the running instance (current user vs admin-like current user running script). I'm now using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook dll to open a new email window and the console application that executes it can run as current user without the need of admin rights. This solved my problem: i'm now able to open a new email window even if outlook is already running.